# Competitive puzzles

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, calculation-puzzle, computer-puzzle, optimization, solvability

Do you know any sort of puzzles that can work in the context of a short competition? In other words, puzzles that have these features:

- The premise should be fairly simple to follow (but the solution might not be so simple).
- The puzzle should be engaging and fun.
- It should have not just one, but several correct answers. However, these answers could be rated under certain criteria, like the more optimal one, or more difficult under certain constraints.
- The puzzle outcome could be linked to other puzzles.

Answer (score 4):

[Al Zimmermann's Programming Contests](http://azspcs.com/) match this description.  The name includes "programming" but does not require it:

> You can enter whether you use a computer, manual calculations, or tea
> leaves to solve the problems. You send me solutions, not programs.

The current contest ends on July 18.